# ¿Cómo pasarle el valor de una variable a una tabla en SQLITE?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo realizar dicho UPDATE para que estas variables se repitan tantas filas existan, al ser llamadas?

Si ejecuto esta query ni me lo aplica, y no puedo usar WHERE ni NRO como referencia porque no existe un rango como tal. Simplemente quiero que se repita como tantas filas vacías existan dentro de *ID_cliente* y *Nombre_cliente*.

```
query= (f"UPDATE clientes_compra SET id_cliente = {self.codigo_factura.get()}, nombre_cliente = {self.nombre_factura.get()}" )
```

Comment: y con where id_cliente is null and nombre_cliente  is null ??? no funciona

Comment: Gracias, me funciono.

Comment: Ponlo entonces como respuesta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: Saludos, no lo he hecho, porque no veo esa opcion en ninguna parte.